# Where is the .emacs.d folder located for Emacs on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, emacs

Where is the `.emacs.d` folder located on `Windows 10` machines? I am using the [official GNU Emacs for Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

I tried <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `user-init-file` and got:

> user-init-file is a variable defined in ‘C source code’. Its value is
>   "~/.emacs"

but no such folder exists.

This is different from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt) in that this is Emacs compiled for Windows, so I don't think the folder it looks for is the equivalent of it on *NIX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the alternative for ~ (user's home directory) on Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: The message is telling you that your home directory is `~/`. Look there. By default there is no init file, but you can create one by `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or whatever you want. See the Emacs manual, node [Windows HOME](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html).

Comment: usually in this location   `C:\Users\<CURRENT_USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`

Answer (score 5):

TLDR:
I fixed this by creating an environment variable called `HOME` that pointed to my home directory (for me it was `C:\Users\kuwze`) which contained my `.emacs.d` folder.

The steps to figure this out:
Using <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> and selecting

> - Emacs W32 FAQ: (efaq-w32).    FAQs about Emacs on MS Windows.

I was able to find this useful information:

> ## 3.5 Where do I put my init file?
>
> On Windows, the ‘.emacs’ file may be called ‘_emacs’ for backward
>   compatibility with DOS and FAT filesystems where filenames could not
>   start with a dot.  Some users prefer to continue using such a name due
>   to historical problems various Windows tools had in the past with file
>   names that begin with a dot.  In Emacs 22 and later, the init file may
>   also be called ‘.emacs.d/init.el’.  Many of the other files that are
>   created by lisp packages are now stored in the ‘.emacs.d’ directory
>   too, so this keeps all your Emacs related files in one place.
>
> All the files mentioned above should go in your ‘HOME’ directory.
>   The ‘HOME’ directory is determined by following the steps below:
>
> 1. If the environment variable ‘HOME’ is set, use the directory it
>       indicates.
> 2. If the registry entry ‘HKCU\SOFTWARE\GNU\Emacs\HOME’ is set, use
>       the directory it indicates.
> 3. If the registry entry ‘HKLM\SOFTWARE\GNU\Emacs\HOME’ is set, use
>       the directory it indicates.  Not recommended, as it results in
>       users sharing the same HOME directory.
> 4. If ‘C:.emacs’ exists, then use ‘C:/’.  This is for backward
>       compatibility, as previous versions defaulted to ‘C:/’ if ‘HOME’
>       was not set.
> 5. Use the user’s AppData directory, usually a directory called
>       ‘AppData’ under the user’s profile directory, the location of which
>       varies according to Windows version and whether the computer is
>       part of a domain.
>
>    Within Emacs, <~> at the beginning of a file name is expanded to
>      your ‘HOME’ directory, so you can always find your ‘.emacs’ file by
>      typing the command ‘C-x C-f ~/.emacs’.

Answer (score 1):

Open your home directory in Emacs Dired with: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> `~/` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You may or may not already have a `~/.emacs.d` directory. If not, you can create it yourself from that Dired buffer with:

<kbd>+</kbd> `.emacs.d` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

Also see the manual: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Windows HOME` <kbd>RET</kbd>