# starting jar with VM-options

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a runnable jar-file which I want to start from a batch file. However the jar-file has to be started with a VM-option. The following batch file starts the jar file (in a static way).

```
java -Djava.security.policy=C:\Users\uname\
\src\main\java\rmi\client.policy 
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file://C:/Users/uname/Documents/Folder
/anotherFolder/target/classes/ -jar %~dp0jarfile.jar %*

pause
```

btw: I know that

> \src\main\java\rmi\client.policy

is not in a jar file yet, but I'm assuming that everybody has this file structure already on his machine.

However, I want to be able to start the jar file with a relative path, so that every Windows10 (x64) user can use my jar file system-independently. How to achieve that via batch?

Answer (score 0):

Replace each reference to user home `C:\Users\...` with `%userprofile%` variable as per [this answer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt).

```
java -Djava.security.policy=%userprofile%\src\main\java\rmi\client.policy 
     -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file://%userprofile%/Documents/Folder/anotherFolder/target/classes/ 
     -jar %~dp0teamFour-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar %*
```

or switch to `%userprofile%` directory with `cd` before executing `java` and depend on relative paths.