# How to overcome the save: couldnot find backup file error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have jmx file that I have saved in a folder in downloads, I have opened it on JMeter did some changes and when I click on save I get a error in log viewer panel as:

```
ERROR o.a.j.g.a.Save: Could not backup file! Backup directory does not exist, is not a directory or could not be created!  <C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\backups>
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Can you run JMeter as administrator? Seems like folder permissions issue

Comment: Yeah when run as Administrator I don't see the error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's default backup directory is `backups` located inside JMeter Home, in order to be able to get benefits from backups you need to have write access to this folder.

So either make sure that the user has [write permissions](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/) to `C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\backups`

or change the backup folder location to the folder where your user has write access (normally it's [home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt)) by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.gui.action.save.backup_directory=C:/Users/your-user-name-here/jmeter/backups
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [JMX Backup configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#backup)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)